# Initializing Multiple Variables in a FOR Loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm a student trying to figure out how to fix a seemingly simple problem. I keep getting an error while trying to initialize 2 variables in a FOR loop. I'm trying to create rows for a game board. Why am I getting this error?

This is the method:

```
public String [] board;

public void printBoard(){
            for(int i, j = 0; i < this.board.length; i++, j++)
                if(j > 10)
                    System.out.println();
                else
                    System.out.print(this.board[i]);

> java:39: error: variable i might not have been initialized
```

Comment: Judging by the code, you probably also need to split the loop, to have a nested loop, in order to reach all game board pieces. As is, you will only hit the diagonals.

Comment: In java everything is very well documented  before doing for loop just see basic syntax , and still if by mistake there is any error  if you  paste it to google  it would diffidently  be a better option , still if you dont find solution the  post  here

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because you didn't initialized variable `i`, maybe zero or else.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < this.board.length; i++, j++)
            if(j > 10)
                System.out.println();
            else
                System.out.print(this.board[i]);
```

Don't forget to initialize a variable If some objects are using it.

Answer (score 4):

`i` in fact has not been initialized.  `for(int i=0, j=0;.... );` will do the trick for you.

Answer (score -1):

This is Syntax. I think this will help you to initialize more than one variable 
  for(int k = 0, dcount = 1; k < count; k++, dcount++)
{

}

Comment: Well this topic is 4 yo, and the answer have been found since. Then I don't think your answer is necessary since it does not add anything to the other answers.